# Loading Features from Source Vector in OL 6.4.3 - Features aren't Showing

Tags: openlayers, geojson, openlayers-6

I've been handed down an application that was using OpenLayers 3 and was tasked with updating it to OpenLayers 6.4.3. The issue I am having is with the tooltip popup for the feature points on the map. The application is using ol-ext for popups (ol.overlay.popup). The points show up just fine on the map, correct location and all, but their associated tooltips show up as [Object, object] instead of being populated with the feature data. After console.logging my way up the ladder, I figured out the source vector is having issues with the GeoJSON. It either isn't fetching the features, or it is but isn't able to render them onto the map for some reason. I have checked the format in the JSON and it's fine. Below is how I'm using the source vector:

```
_this.vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: serverUrl + '/features'
  wrapX: false,
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  })
})
console.log(_this.vectorSource); //this shows up as [Object, object]
```

This is a sample from my GeoJSON:

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [
    {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "properties" : {
        "name" : "",
        "description" : "",
        "type" : ""
      },
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          -117.7679443359375,
          32.94789123535156
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The application was using GeoExt store for storing the features, but I had to removed GeoExt. I was able to successfully remove any dependencies on GeoExt, though. The vector source was never involved with GeoExt directly, so I don't think that's the issue. I believe it has to do something with the OpenLayers update, but I can't seem to find what it is. The tooltip was working just fine before the update. Also, there are no errors whatsoever, and the JSON file is fetching in the network tab on my browser just fine. I looked through every question on SO involving GeoJSON and vector source but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck on this for weeks.

Comment: There will be no features immediately after defining the source.  The url will not be fetched until the source is set in a vector layer, the layer added to a map and the map is opened.

Comment: So this source is set in a cluster layer I have (ol.layer.AnimatedCluster), and that cluster layer is added to my map.